# Order mysql results by connection collation rather than structure collation

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation

I have a multilingual platform. I need it to sort results depending on the prefered collation for the mysql connection. Not by mysql structure collation.

Is this possible to do without rewriting every query? I don't wanna end up with example `order by name asc collate utf8_swedish_ci` in every query.

`set names utf8 collate utf8_swedish_ci` doesn't work as the results order å before b like utf8_general_ci does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET NAMES` stuff handles the character set used for queries and query metadata such as column names. It has no effect on the handling of data from your tables.  See here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-connection.html

You asked whether it's possible to use a particular collation (presumably a user preference setting) to order results without rewriting queries.  The answer is no.

This is partly because collations are bound into indexes when the indexes are constructed or updated. That's very good for performance, but unfortunately not in your kind of pan-European multi-collation application.

Comment: Very informative good anser. Found out utf8_bin was The best universal solution.